# 'state is not defined' and its also says 'This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed', even after defining state

Tags: reactjs

Getting the below issue. I have tried myself but no luck.

[image]

I have defined the state and onFormSubmit, but I dont know why I am getting this error.

[image]

To resolve the issue, I have uninstalled the create-react-app using `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` and installed again using `npm install -g create-react-app` and then created the project again using `create-react-app videos`.  And finally I wrote the code again and entered 'npm start', i am getting the same above issues.

Comment: I would suggest posting your code in CodeSandbox or the like and providing a link to it. You're not going to get many answers if you're posting code as images. The code you've provided is incomplete, so it's not really possible to diagnose. Right off the bat, if you're using class properties, i.e. "state", you would need a Babel plugin to handle that, as that is not vanilla Javascript. Also, this is not the idiomatic way of creating state for you components. If you look at some more code examples, state is always an instance of the class and declared inside of the class constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting these error because of function binding.

The following piece of code will work for you.

```
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";

class App extends PureComponent {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      term: ''
    };
    this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  onFormSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('Term: ', this.state.term)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
        <input
          type='text'
          value={this.state.term}
          onChange={(e) => {
            this.setState({
              term: e.target.value
            })
          }}
        />
      </form>
    </div >
  );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Here is the code https://react-bwwutc.stackblitz.io

Thank you.